# Second Order Low Pass Filter Proteus Simulation

Tags: filter, low-pass, proteus

I am trying to simulate the following circuit on proteus but on the oscilloscope I see the signal has no change in between input and output. In accordance with the data sheet (LM348) I am supplying 18V from pin 11 and -18V from pin 4. I have also attached pin 4 to ground and tried other possible ways but the oscilloscpoe shows the same result. Input voltage is 100mVp-p, frequency 2kHz. What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

[image]

Comment: (This schematic is scarily similar to [another one posted, recently.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/563334/38098) But of course the question is different.) If you are doing a transient analysis, you probably want to hook up a small AC signal, via an adequate capacitor in series, to your input resistor point. This circuit can work with DC, but it's usually used with AC signals. I'm a bit confused by what's at the input node there, though. And I don't use that software. So I'll leave this to others to worry about.

Comment: To debug , remove R6 and cap and check for linear gain on 1st stage of 10k/1k5. This ought to be a BPF on 1st stage and 2nd order 9kHz filter on stages 2 and 3 is inverted. I also do not use Proteus. Maybe your signal source is floating and this is all common mode floating signal which explains why the output is not inverted .  Aha the scope has to be grounded ?  And why is ch B shorted to D yet not the same wrong signal.... hmmm buggy

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Actually, the whole thing is a low-pass filter. In fact, \$R_1\$ doesn't even appear in the roll-off frequency calculation. Not in any way, at all. You can change it in any way you want and it has zero effect. It is only used to control the damping factor.

Comment: Canberk, pin 4 is the (+) rail and pin 11 is the (-) rail. Have you tried that?

Comment: @jonk I know R1 affects the 1st stage output producing a damping  controlled by R1 attenuation or gain with high Q BPF.. but what I meant was remove =outputs and inputs R6.. and find out where scope ground comes from

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Well, I wrote some stuff about it. Hopefully, it's some small help to the OP. I'm not having any difficulties with the schematic, at all. Unfortunately, I don't use the tool they do. Oh, well.

Comment: @jonk Notice how all signals are not inverting and the same as the input. This suggests a lack of common ground between hidden generator and scope grounds in Proteus assumptions.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I see a bunch of weird things connected to the input: an AC-looking thing and a DC-looking thing with "1" next to it. I have no clue about those. It doesn't look right. But then I don't use that software, so what do I know? I'm not having any trouble is all that I can see, for now. It just works like it is supposed to work. So it's a problem with the OP's use of their tool, I think.

Comment: @jonk I ditto all of that. 100 picovolt input DC offset is ok  but not for output offset of a 741.

Comment: Check the wires at the B, C, and D inputs on the oscilloscope, they look like they might be all shorted together, which means the whole 1st stage is bypassed. Don't draw the wires straight across the pins, as you did, leave some room, at least a grid point wide.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen seems to be correct although dots are normally added to junctions of 3 or 4 wires, there are 4 channels and the sig gen could be a 0 Ohm type without 50 Ohms and shorting the input to the 1st stage output. They ought to be non-overlapping traces from4 signals to 4 channels as the last stage is not connected to scope.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't have Proteus, so I don't know if it does, indeed, short out the pins, but it seems like a sensible choice to leave at least one grid point tolerance, especially if you're asking for help on ee.se because you can't debug it yourself.

Comment: There is no short circuit at the oscillator pins. For them to be connected there shall be a dot sign indicating that they are connected.

Comment: I have tried every possible combination. It seems that LM348 doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your schematic drawn up in LTspice:

[image]

(I've used \$U_4\$ instead of \$U_3\$ and I've added some resistors at the (+) inputs of each opamp.)

The transfer function is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=\mathcal{H}\left(s\right)&=K\frac{\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}\\\\
&\text{where,}\\\\
A_{v}&=\frac{R_5}{R_4}\\\\
K&=\frac1{A_v}\frac{R_6}{R_2}\\\\
\omega_{_0}&=\frac1{\sqrt{\frac1{A_v} R_3 R_6 C_1 C_2}}\\\\
\zeta &= \frac1{2\sqrt{A_v}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{C_2}{C_1}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{R_3 R_6}}{R_1}
\end{align*}$$

If you set \$R_3=R_6=R\$ and \$R_4=R_5\$ and \$C_1=C_2=C\$, then this nicely reduces to:

$$\begin{align*}
K&=\frac{R}{R_2}\\\\
\omega_{_0}&=\frac1{R \cdot C}\\\\
\zeta &= \frac1{2}\cdot \frac{R}{R_1}
\end{align*}$$

Given that you select a convenient value for \$C\$, you then simply select a value for \$R\$ in order to set a desired \$\omega_{_0}\$. Once that's done, you use \$R_2\$ to set the overall voltage gain and you set \$R_1\$ to set the damping factor. It's really simple!! Which is the cool thing about this particular schematic. (Also known as a *state-variable* filter.)

Bearing in mind that the gain-bandwidth of the LM348 is \$1\:\text{MHz}\$, here's a Bode plot from the above, using LTspice:

[image]

We expect about a low-pass band voltage gain of \$20\log_{10}\left(\frac{15\:\text{k}\Omega}{1.5\:\text{k}\Omega}\right)=20\:\text{dB}\$. Which the above shows.

If I run a transient analysis (.TRAN) then I get the following with an input of \$2\:\text{kHz}\$ with a peak-to-peak voltage of \$1\:\text{V}\$:

[image]

Which looks about as you'd expect, since \$K=10\$.

Now, from the Bode plot I expect that at \$f=100\:\text{kHz}\$ that \$k\approx \frac1{10}\$. So let's plot that out using a transient plot:

[image]

Almost exactly as expected, yes?

Frankly? I'm not having any troubles at all. I suspect that you may have not connected up the (+) and (-) rails, properly. That's the place I'd be looking, right now. I simply do not have problems with the circuit. It works just as analysis would suggest.

I can't tell you specifically what is wrong because I don't use your Spice tool and I really don't know what you did wrong. But it's clear that when I attempt to replicate your issues using a different tool, LTspice, then I find exactly what I do expect to see.

Hopefully, someone familiar with your tool will be able to find your error. I apologize that I cannot do more than I have.